# How can I get function names defined in Lisp script?

Tags: java, lisp

I have a Lisp file with some functions defined [ (defun ... ].

Is there an easy way to get all function names defined in the script using Java?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use some of the code from [A Small Lisp interpreter in Java](http://yama-linux.cc.kagoshima-u.ac.jp/~yamanoue/researches/java/Lisp/Lisp.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know, which functions are defined in a certain package, you cane use `with-package-iterator` macro. Like this:

```
(with-package-iterator (next (find-package 'test) :internal)
  (loop :for (more? sym) := (multiple-value-list (next))
        :if (fboundp sym) :collect sym :into rez 
        :else :unless more? :do (return rez)))
```

If you want to just extract functions from a script(-file), the easiest way seems to be scanning it with a regex `"\\(defun (.+)\\s"` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In very simple cases, you can use regular expressions.  In slightly less simple cases, implementing an S-expression reader might be a reasonable approach (you might even get away with ignoring reader macros altogether).  In the general case, though, especially if macrology is involved, consider embedding [Armed Bear Common Lisp](http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/), which is a Java implementation of Common Lisp, and using the `with-package-iterator` form Vsevolod mentioned.